# Cant Restart Apache Server

Tags: server

I have written code in terminal :

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And got the response :

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

What is this error?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this message from appearing, you should say to it that you want to serve from localhost by adding the following line into your `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Then add the line

```
ServerName localhost
```

Save and exit then try to restart:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: When I got change   " /etc/apache2/apache2.conf" file it can't change.

Comment: check the edit above